Problema al inicializar base de datos con python flask y mysql workbench
Al tratar de inicializar mi base de datos con python flask y MySQL workbench me arroja este error...
$ flask init-db
Database host: localhost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 327, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Access denied for user 'your_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 1105, in main
    cli.main()
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 386, in decorator
    return ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\Python sin Fronteras\Proyecto-Mailer\mailerapp\app\db.py", line 36, in init_db_command
    init_db()
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\Python sin Fronteras\Proyecto-Mailer\mailerapp\app\db.py", line 26, in init_db
    db, c = get_db()
            ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\Python sin Fronteras\Proyecto-Mailer\mailerapp\app\db.py", line 10, in get_db
    g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 322, in connect   
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1360, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\python sin fronteras\proyecto-mailer\mailerapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 332, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'your_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
(venv)

Acá mi archivo init.py
import os

os.environ['FLASK_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
os.environ['FLASK_DATABASE_USER'] = 'your_username'
os.environ['FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'your_password'
os.environ['FLASK_DATABASE'] = 'your_database_name'

from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    print(f"Database host: {os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_HOST')}")  # Añade esta línea

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SENDGRID_KEY=os.environ.get('SENDGRIP_API_KEY'),
        SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY'),
        DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_HOST'),
        DATABASE_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        DATABASE_USER=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_USER'),
        DATABASE=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE'),
    )

    from . import db

    db.init_app(app)

    return app

Mi archivo db.py
import mysql.connector

import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from .schema import instructions

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=current_app.config['DATABASE_HOST'],
            user=current_app.config['DATABASE_USER'],
            password=current_app.config['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
            database=current_app.config['DATABASE']
        )
        g.c = g.db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    return g.db, g.c

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)
    
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db, c = get_db()

    for i in instructions:
        c.execute(i)

    db.commit()

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    init_db()
    click.echo("Base de datos inicializada")

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)

Mi archivo schema.py
instructions = [
    'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS email;',
    """
        CREATE TABLE email (
            id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            email TEXT NOT NULL,
            subject TEXT NOT NULL,
            content TEXT NOT NULL
        )
    """
]

mi archivo .env
FLASK_DATABASE_HOST=localhost
FLASK_DATABASE_USER=
FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD=
FLASK_DATABASE=prueba

Mi pip list.
$ pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
blinker                1.8.2
click                  8.1.7
colorama               0.4.6
Flask                  3.0.3
itsdangerous           2.2.0
Jinja2                 3.1.4
MarkupSafe             2.1.5
mysql-connector-python 8.4.0
pip                    24.0
python-dotenv          1.0.1
setuptools             70.0.0
Werkzeug               3.0.3
wheel                  0.43.0
(venv) 

El usuario que estoy usando en MySQL Workbench tiene prácticamente todos los privilegios ya que soy el administrador y es en mi portátil personal. He realizado todo tipo de pruebas desinstalando todas las librerías usadas en mi (venv) y reinstalándolas nuevamente, realicé la prueba de conexión de mi base de datos y resultó satisfactoria, no sé donde puede estar el error... Gracias de antemano por la ayuda al respecto!!!

MySQL Workbench es un programa para Administrar bases de datos que no tiene Relacion con python... incluso nisiquiera es necesario que las credenciales de uno te funcionen en otro ... el problema es otro ...

Pero mi app está basada en python y flask y con ello me conecto a mi base de datos...

entonces tu problema es entre python y el servidor mysql .... mysql workbench no tiene nada que ver ...
